# COMODO cert signed applet still 'self-signed'

Tags: java-8, pfx, jarsigner

I have valid COMODO certificate which I use to sign DLLs. I now need to sign applet.jar and for this I used this command: 
`jarsigner "PATH_TO\my.jar" -storetype pkcs12 -keystore "PATH_TO\cert.pfx" 1 -tsa http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp`

As result I get warning:

> The signer's certificate chain is not validated.

And my applet is considered as self-signed. I found this solution: [The signer’s certificate chain is not validated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47920119/jarsigner-the-signer-s-certificate-chain-is-not-validated) and the same [here](https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO17686), but now when I try to sign jar with exported certificate I get this error:

> jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available

I tried to add this to command line `-sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA256` but nothing changed.

Can anybody help with this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by solution from original question, BUT key point is that you can NOT use Windows 10 for this trick, I used Windows 7 and it works just fine.

Why? no idea...